# 1980's (maybe 70's) Scifi book series about other planets which were colonized one by native Americans, one by Mennonites, one by Mormons etc

Tags: story-identification, books, soft-sci-fi

I'm trying to remember the name of a book I read in high school (about 1984) that was about other planets which were colonized one by native Americans,  one by Mennonites,  one by Mormons etc. Very strict rules on each planet and that's all I can remember.  Although I read it in high school,  I got it from the high school library so who knows how old the book was.

Comment: Can you not remember anything at all of the plot? Who the main characters were? Did the planets interact? How did the main characters find the planets? What happened? Did they land on them? etc. If you remember anything else at all, remember every detail you add means people are more likely to find this, you can [edit] your question to include those details.

Comment: Similarities to Eric Frank Russell's "The Great Explosion". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Great_Explosion  But it doesn't quite line up.

Comment: Orson Scott Card's 1979 novel _[A Planet Called Treason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Planet_Called_Treason)_  has a situation like this, except that different peoples settled different regions on one planet.

Comment: Reminiscent of John Barnes [Thousand Cultures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Million_Open_Doors) series, in which each planet is settled with one or more revived cultures from Earth -- in one case, with a disastrous clash between Tamil and Mayan cultures. But that series was published from 1992 to 2006 and I don't recall Mennonites or Mormons being involved.

Comment: THAT'S IT! The Great Explosion Eric Frank Russell. Wow You guys rock. Thank you